# Will my wife and son being away to see family for 3 weeks without me effect my 6 month old son and I's relationship?

Tags: travel

My wife was planning to visit her family for 3 weeks.  We recently did a trip to see them for a few weeks together as a family when he was 4 months so he knows the family and house and he is very well cared for there.  (3 women him :) )

I wanted to know if she goes on the next trip and I do not come with them will there be any adverse effects for our son?  We currently have a great relationship, he smiles at me every time I walk in the room to see the little cutie and I would not want to spoil that in some way.

I have spent a 5 days away and he was all giggles and smiles when I returned.

I am assuming skype would not work with a child this young but maybe it would be reassuring to hear my voice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

3 weeks really isn't a concern, he will still remember you, and be all smiles when he gets back. Plan something special for his return, just him and you for an afternoon, and set up a couple of skypes by all means.